# Zenmap results at odds with custom port scan

Tags: python, linux, server, nmap

I ran a scan with Zenmap on my linux server and found the following ports to be open

[image]

So I went over my python script below and ran it

[image]

But I was given this output!

[image]

How would this be the case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which parameter do you use for your nmapscan?

Comment: Please use `<p>` blocks to include code and output instead of using screenshots. It makes it easier for other users to find your question via search, makes it more accessible to users with screen readers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `try` block covers a lot of functions, and `except` is catching everything and calling it "port closed." At minimum, it could be any of the following situations:

- Failed to create a socket.
- Failed to connect to the server.
- Connected but the server disconnected before you tried to `send`.
- Connected and sent, but server disconnected before you tried to `recv`

Nmap would consider either of the second two as "open" because the initial handshake succeeded. Your script considers them "closed" instead.